# What is wrong with this JSON string?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing, web-scraping

This is the first time I am working with JSON and I am hung up here.

I wanted to parse this JSON String called `tackles` using `json.loads(tackles)` in Python and got the error `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

After this I used `json.loads(str(tackles))` but it failed with the following error `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

So what exactly do I need to change so that it works?
What would be great is an example that shows how I can print all `tackleWontotal` values next to the names of the teams.

Here is the JSON String:

```
"{
    u'statColumns': [
        u'apps',
        u'subOn',
        u'minsPlayed',
        u'tackleWonTotal',
        u'challengeLost',
        u'tackleTotalAttempted'
    ],
    u'paging': {
        u'firstRecordIndex': 0,
        u'resultsPerPage': 0,
        u'lastRecordIndex': 0,
        u'totalPages': 0,
        u'currentPage': 1,
        u'totalResults': 0
    },
    u'teamTableStats': [ {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 10.75,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'ManCity',
        u'ranking': 1,
        u'rating': 7.297500000000002,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 14.75,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'ManchesterCity',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 167,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 25.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 8.5,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Arsenal',
        u'ranking': 2,
        u'rating': 7.039793956043958,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 20.75,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Arsenal',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 13,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 29.25
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 10.25,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Swansea',
        u'ranking': 3,
        u'rating': 6.999136904761905,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 16.25,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Swansea',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-wls',
        u'teamId': 259,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 26.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 7.75,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Southampton',
        u'ranking': 4,
        u'rating': 6.945068681318677,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 16.75,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Southampton',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 18,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 24.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 7.75,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Leicester',
        u'ranking': 5,
        u'rating': 6.922499999999998,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 23.25,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Leicester',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 14,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 31.0
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 4.75,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'AstonVilla',
        u'ranking': 6,
        u'rating': 6.909995421245423,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 19.75,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'AstonVilla',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 24,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 24.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 8.0,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'CrystalPalace',
        u'ranking': 7,
        u'rating': 6.89214285714286,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 16.0,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'CrystalPalace',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 162,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 24.0
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 7.75,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Everton',
        u'ranking': 8,
        u'rating': 6.876071428571427,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 16.5,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Everton',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 31,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 24.25
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 10.5,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'WestHam',
        u'ranking': 9,
        u'rating': 6.86017857142857,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 20.0,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'WestHam',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 29,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 30.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 8.75,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'ManUtd',
        u'ranking': 10,
        u'rating': 6.855535714285715,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 19.5,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'ManchesterUnited',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 32,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 28.25
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 7.0,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Watford',
        u'ranking': 11,
        u'rating': 6.850975274725273,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 21.5,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Watford',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 27,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 28.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 10.0,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Liverpool',
        u'ranking': 12,
        u'rating': 6.85006868131868,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 20.25,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Liverpool',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 26,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 30.25
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 7.5,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Tottenham',
        u'ranking': 13,
        u'rating': 6.777403846153845,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 19.5,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Tottenham',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 30,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 27.0
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 9.25,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'WestBrom',
        u'ranking': 14,
        u'rating': 6.69517857142857,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 18.25,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'WestBromwichAlbion',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 175,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 27.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 9.25,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Chelsea',
        u'ranking': 15,
        u'rating': 6.659107142857143,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 15.25,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Chelsea',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 15,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 24.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 11.5,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Sunderland',
        u'ranking': 16,
        u'rating': 6.656263736263735,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 26.75,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Sunderland',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 16,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 38.25
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 10.25,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Bournemouth',
        u'ranking': 17,
        u'rating': 6.64839285714286,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 17.25,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Bournemouth',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 183,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 27.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 8.5,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Stoke',
        u'ranking': 18,
        u'rating': 6.600714285714285,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 19.25,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Stoke',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 96,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 27.75
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 7.75,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Norwich',
        u'ranking': 19,
        u'rating': 6.59885989010989,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 17.75,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'Norwich',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 168,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 25.5
    },
    {
        u'seasonId': 0,
        u'tournamentRegionId': 252,
        u'challengeLost': 8.25,
        u'minsPlayed': 360,
        u'name': u'Newcastle',
        u'ranking': 20,
        u'rating': 6.596428571428575,
        u'apps': 4,
        u'tackleWonTotal': 18.25,
        u'tournamentName': u'PremierLeague',
        u'tournamentRegionCode': None,
        u'teamName': u'NewcastleUnited',
        u'seasonName': None,
        u'regionCode': u'gb-eng',
        u'teamId': 23,
        u'tournamentId': 2,
        u'tackleTotalAttempted': 26.5
    } ] }"
```

Here is my full code:

```
import json
import requests

url = "http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetTeamStatistics"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

def GetResponse(category, subcategory):
    params = {
            'category': category,
            'subcategory': subcategory,
            'statsAccumulationType': '0',
            'field': 'Overall',
            'tournamentOptions': '',
            'timeOfTheGameStart': '0',
            'timeOfTheGameEnd': '5',
            'stageId': '12496',
            'sortBy': 'Rating',
            'sortAscending': 'false',
            'page': '1',
            'includeZeroValues': '',
            'numberOfTeamsToPick': '', 
            'isCurrent': 'true',
            'formation': ''
            }  
    return requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

tackles = GetResponse('tackles','success');

parsedtackles = json.loads(str(tackles))
print tackles
```

Now I was able to solve the issue. Thanks to everyone who replied, your response was a great help for me.

Comment: The `u` prefix on the keys is not valid json. This looks like someone pretty-printed a python dictionary.

Comment: As others have pointed out, it is not valid json. The values need to enclosed within double quotes. you can use this to validate your json http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this isn't JSON; among other things, JSON needs its keys to be double-quoted (not single-quoted) and forbids the Python `u` prefix.

If this is actually the data you're getting, you're better off using `ast.literal_eval`. ([Docs here.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval))

That said, I'd look a little farther back at when you say you're trying to run `json.loads(str(tackles))`.

`str(tackles)` doesn't produce JSON; `json.dumps(tackles)` does. If you just want to test JSON generation/parsing, try `json.loads(json.dumps(tackles))`.

Comment: Thanks, now with json.loads(json.dumps(tackles)) this doesn't result in an error anymore. Now please how can I look up the teamName of the say the 3rd team in the dictionary?

Comment: `parsedtackles["teamTableStats"][2]["teamName"]`

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that is not a proper JSON string. The **u'** is for Python unicode string object and probably somewhere there your original JSON was turned into Python object and then stringified.

Check where the change is taking part and then eliminate it to provide a proper JSON to load() method

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the full code to the question details. Do you see where this happens?

Comment: hm.. due to [Requests documentation[(http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) this is the JSON format being returned from **requests.get(...).json()**. Instead of this maybe try 

    `import json
    import requests
    ...
    response = requests.get(...)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)`

sorry for no newlines

Answer (score 0):

or simply

```
parsedtackles = str (json.dumps(tackles))
```